# Import HTML table with CSS to MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, html, css

I have created a table below using `R` with HTML code attached at the end of the question.

[image]

The default output from `R` fits perfectly my need, but I need table to be shown and editable in MS Word. I tried: i) copy-and-paste the table from firefox to MS Word; and ii) open the html file using MS Word. Both give me table with distorted style.

Is there anyway to copy the table as it is seen below from HTML to word?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
 <style>table { border-collapse:collapse; border:none; }
th { border-bottom: 1px solid; }
table td { padding:0.2cm; }
.summary td { padding-top:0.1cm; padding-bottom:0.1cm }
.colnames td { font-style:italic }
.firstsumrow { border-top:1px solid }
.lasttablerow { border-bottom: double; }
.topborder { border-top:2px solid }
.depvarhead { text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px solid }
.topcontentborder { border-top:double }
.annorow { border-top:2px solid }
.annostyle { text-align:right }
</style> 
</head>
<body> 
 <table>
   <tr class="topborder">
    <td rowspan="2"><em>Predictors</em></td> 
     <td colspan="3" class="depvarhead"><em>Dependent Variables</em></td> 
   </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="3">Barthel-Index</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr class="colnames">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>B (CI)</td><td>std. Beta</td><td>p</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="topcontentborder"> 
     <td>(Intercept)</td> 
     <td>93.76 (85.95-101.57)</td> <td></td><td><b>0.000</b></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr>
     <td>Carer's Age</td> 
     <td>-0.55 (-0.69--0.41)</td> <td>-0.25</td><td><b>0.000</b></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr class="summary firstsumrow">
    <td>Observations</td>
     <td colspan="3">880</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="summary">
     <td>R<sup>2</sup> / adj. R<sup>2</sup></td>
     <td colspan="3">0.061 / 0.060</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="summary">
     <td>AIC</td>
     <td colspan="3">8424.34</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="annorow">
    <td>Notes</td><td class="annostyle" colspan="3"><em>* p&lt;0.005&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;** p&lt;0.01&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*** p&lt;0.001</em></td>
  </tr>
</table> 
 </body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Import to libreoffice, save as .doc and open in Word.  Libreoffice does a better job of importing html tables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can open HTML files *as* HTML files in word. So save the file to a location and then open it with word.

Comment: nope, i tried but the format still gets distorted, actually i tried that before the question is asked

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with insert object. In the `Insert` ribbon, under the `Text` tab, go to `Object` - `Text from file`.

You may have to alter it afterwards, such as formatting etc as there *some* subtle differences but it isn't bad!

[image]

Comment: sorry for being picky, but I need to repeat the formatting work for several dozens of tables, it would be good if formatting can also be inherited to MS Word.

Comment: I can't see where your state that in your original question.